# Google Script Run Function IF text in another sheet's column contains a 'specific text'

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, data-extraction

I've done extensive search for this, but none of them seems to work. They all just give me a blank sheet.
[Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pl6Rd9rp9TdxTd_zvXMBqjmv3rgmuM2EFdPv9jGIWD0/edit?usp=sharing)

Basically I have a function that extracts data from Col. B in DATA, to Result. Then does some other things, split, trim etc...

I want to run this function when the text in Col. A in DATA is 250P.

[image]

So it would be like: IF (DATA!A1:A contains text "250p" then run function EXTRACT).

This is the code I have as of now:

```
//this extract works fine but I just need this to work for only those with value 250 in Col A//

function EXTRACT() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').setFormula('=EXTRACTDATA(DATA!A1:A)');

}

function IF250() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('DATA');
  var range = sheet.getRange('DATA!A1:A');
  var values = range.getValues();

  if (values[i] == "250g") {
    EXTRACT();
```

Better yet, If I can have the data set in 2 separate sheets. The 250s in one sheet & 500s in one sheet. But this is not necessary.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't fully understand your goal. You want to parse the data in a way that when the colum A contains a 250 move to another sheet and the same form 500? Please, add a sample sheet, the one you linked is not accessible.

Comment: Sorry, editing enabled in sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pl6Rd9rp9TdxTd_zvXMBqjmv3rgmuM2EFdPv9jGIWD0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: My goal is to extract data from the original sheet to new sheets. Leaving the original sheet as is, and then run the function on just particular data sets. So its sort of like get a list of all the 250p ones & then the 500p ones, just the data in them and not the "250p" column itself.  I hope this explains

Comment: added a solution after checking the desired OUTPUT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing your sheet, this is a possible solution

###### `Code.gs`

```js
const sS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
function grabData() {
  const sheetIn = sS.getSheetByName('data')
  const sheetOut = sS.getSheetByName('Desired Outcome')
  const range = 'A2:B'
  /* Grab all the data from columns A and B and filter it */
  const values = sheetIn.getRange(range).getValues().filter(n => n[0])
  /* Retrieve only the names if it containes 250p */
  /* In format [[a], [b], ...] */
  const parsedValues = values.map((arr) => {
    const [type, name] = arr
    if (type.toLowerCase().includes('250p')) {
      return name.split('\n')
    }
  })
    .filter(n => n)
    .flat()
    .map(n => [n])
  /* Add the values to the Desired Outcome Sheet */
  sheetOut
    .getRange(sheetOut.getLastRow() + 1, 1, parsedValues.length)
    .setValues(parsedValues)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Emel. Your solution work perfectly and it cut off extra functions and steps that I had on top of my script to split the data into rows too. Thank you again :) :)

Comment: can I get help from you for this formula. I also want to put this again in the same script, to grab the the rows that say '400p'. I updated the script to create new sheets, and grab data separate into those 2. Only thing, even though I changed all the 250s to 400p, it still grabs only the 250p ones into that sheet. Is there anything I should change here to grab a separate set of data?

Comment: Post another question on this topic and try to get help from there. In any case, this would be the guide lines: 1. Create a new sheet and a var for it `const sheet400 = sS.getSheetByName('400p')`, 2. Change the value inside the if of the map function of parsed values to `if (type.toLowerCase().includes('400p')) {` 3. Ensure that you are appending to the right sheet : `sheet400.getRange...`

Comment: Thank you Emel. I figured it out. I thought it would be too many questions if I might post another one related to this post, that's why I didn't post another question. Thank you for explaining :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
var values = range.getValues();
```

to

```
var values = range.getDisplayValues()
```

As this will read the value that is shown. Try logging the values with both to see why! (Blank)

You are also not currently iterating, or looping, your values.

If you're just looking to see if the column contains a cell containing the value `250p`, try:

```
function IF250() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(`DATA`)

  const valueExists = sheet.getRange(`A1:A`)
                           .getDisplayValues()
                           .filter(String)
                           .some(row => row.includes(`250P`))

  if (valueExists) EXTRACT()

}
```

Commented:

```
function IF250() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(`DATA`)

  const valueExists = sheet.getRange(`A1:A`)
                           .getDisplayValues()
                           // Remove empty cells (not strictly necessary)
                           .filter(String)
                           // If the values include a row containing `250p` return true.
                           .some(row => row.includes(`250P`)) 
  // If valueExists returns true:
  if (valueExists) EXTRACT()

}
```

Comment: I did put a loop, atleast I hope I did it right. But each time I couldn't save the script because it gave an error with the loop. Attempted to execute IF250, but could not save. This is what I put   for (var i =0,i<values.length;i++){

Comment: Did you test my solution?

Comment: For my original code, replacing with range.getDisplayValues() and even with my old value it now gives me ReferenceError: i is not defined

Comment: I ran your new code, and that returns blank as well.  I've saved it as IFBYNEWAZA in the spreadsheet. Code.gs has the one I wrote